# Почему в строгом режиме отображается объект window?

Tags: javascript, объекты, this

Читаю везде, что при установлении строгого режима **use strict** `this`, находящийся в глобальном контексте выполнения, будет иметь значение `undefined`. То есть проще говоря, `this` не будет иметь значение window, только undefined.

Но я смотрю, что это не совсем так:

```js
'use strict'
let object = {
    f: function () {
        console.log(this);
    },
    r: this
}
object.f(); //object
console.log(object.r); //window

function func() {
    console.log(this); //undefined
}
func();
```

Window выводится, когда происходит обращение к свойству r объекта object. Почему?
И почему тогда в примере с функцией, который расположен ниже, выводится не window, а undefined?

Comment: _this, находящийся в глобальном контексте выполнения, будет иметь значение undefined_ - добавь источник, именно для такой формулировки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Значение `this` зависит от строгого режима, если употребляется внутри функции, как в `func()` у вас в коде. Вне функций в глобальном контексте это будет глобальный объект (в браузерах — `window`) независимо от режима.

То, что в вашем коде `this` употреблено в литерале создания объекта, ничего не меняет. `let object = { r: this }` — тут будет то же самое `this`, что и в `console.log(this)` в глобальном контексте.

См., например, [this: Global context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#global_context):

> In the global execution context (outside of any function), this refers to the global object whether in strict mode or not.

Comment: есть вероятность, что в модулях `this` будет модулем, а не глобальным объектом

Comment: @Grundy В ESM `console.log(this)` даёт `undefined`. В CommonJs `console.log(this === module.exports)` даёт `true`.